# Mxing Present and Past Tense to describe a location

Tags: tense, backshifting

Please check the below sentence where I want to talk about a conversation with my friend about a place or building, to a third person. Should I mix present and past tense in this case as Eiffel Tower will always be in Paris?

> I asked him where the Eiffel Tower **is** located. He told me that the Eiffel tower **is** located in Paris.

Comment: [Here's a related link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161622/facts-in-reported-speech-to-backshift-or-not)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["until something" in reported speech](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161882/until-something-in-reported-speech)

Comment: Also  a possible duplicate of [**Present or Past in "They said they are/were breaking up"**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67228/present-or-past-in-they-said-they-are-were-breaking-up/67239#67239)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question was asked in the past, the form "I asked him" is proper in the past tense. Since the Eiffel Tower has not moved the form "where the Eiffel Tower **is** located" (using the present tense) is just fine. This kind of mixing o tenses  is perfectly normal. One can even mix past and future, as in:

> I asked her yesterday where she would be next July.

If the sentence had been

> I asked him where the Eiffel Tower was located.

it would imply that it used to be located somewhere it now is not, as if it had been moved or destroyed. But of course it has not.

I think the original sentence is perfectly proper.